# How do I override the default template when using Symfony Forms, Twig and SymfonyTwigBridge?

Tags: php, twig, symfony-forms, silex

Im using Symfony and Twig in a Silex application.

I have a registration page with a form in:

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block title %}Welcome to My Example site{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
{{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <p>
        Register for this site and we'll give you free access to cool stuff
        in addition you can subscribe to our premium content.
    </p>
   
    <form  action="{{app.config.site.secureUrl}}/register-handler" method="post">
        <fieldset >
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I get the following error when trying to render the page:

> Twig_Error_Syntax: The filter "trans" does not exist in "form_div_layout.html.twig" at line 35

I've narrowed this down to the Symfony translation extension not being installed and as such the default template located in:

```
vendor\symfony\twigbridge\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form\form_div_layout.html.twig
```

does not render correctly.

I've made a new template based on the one above without the translation functions in.

## Question

how do I get twig to use the new template instead of the default one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use your own template for form, you just have to specify it in the options when you register Twig :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
      'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/[Path_to_views_directory]',
      'twig.class_path' => __DIR__ . '/vendor/twig/lib',
      'twig.form.templates'   => array([path_to_your_overriden_template]),
 )) ;
```

see the documentation : [TwigProvider documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html)

But I think it is better to use the original template and register the translation provider like this :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
      'locale' => '[Your_locale]',
      'translation.class_path' =>  __DIR__ . '/../vendor/symfony/src',
      'translator.messages' => array()
)) ;
```

And if you use validation don't forget to read this cookbook :

[Translation cookbook](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/translating_validation_messages.html)

Hope this will help.

Comment: `'twig.form.templates'` was not the correct key for me. Using `'twig.form.resources'` instead worked. See http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations

Answer (score 1):

You should register the [SymfonyBridgesServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/symfony_bridges.html) and the [TranslationServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/translation.html).

That should give you the trans filter and solve your initial problem.

Comment: Seems like the links are gone?